# Which hard drive failed SMART ? Synology NAS

Tags: hard-disk, nas, synology, smart

I had 2 x 4TB Red Pro drives in a Sinology NAS. One of them was reported as failing (couple of years ago) by Synology. I believe it was a SMART failure. So I pulled out both drives bought a new one and was able to copy all data from the drive that was failing (not failed yet). Both 4 TB drives seem to be working fine when mounted on a linux machine. I can copy data to and from the one reported as "failing" by Synology. The thing is I'm not a 100% sure which drive was reported as "failing" as it was couple of years ago.
Is there a command/test I can run to figure out which drive is failing so I exclude it (or discard it) from my primary NAS ?

I tried smartctl -a /dev/<sda/sdc> for my drives and the self assessment result says "Passed" and I see no errors there.

Update: After running the test recommended by @meuh - "smartctl -t short " I get the following error:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     21687         8359136
```

Comment: the SMART failure should still be there

Comment: Thanks @jsotola. I tried the "smartctl -a <drive>" and that reports as "Passed" and no errors in output. Does Synology run a different test ?

Comment: When you say “I believe it was a SMART failure”, what was it that led you to believe that?

Comment: @StephenKitt, that's all I recall. Synology said that my main drive is failing. I had JBOD setup with no RAID. This was a couple of years ago. I wish I made notes and marked the drive but I didn't. Sorry, wish I could remember more about it.

Comment: Have you tried checking the Notifications - or in the "Log Center"? Both accessible from the GUI "Admin Center"?

Comment: Run an actual test on each drive, eg `smartctl -t short <drive>`. It will tell you how long to wait for it to finish, when you can do a `-a` to get the logged result. If both pass, try the much longer version, `-t long`. You can do both drives simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks @meuh. This helped reveal something, but I do not know how bad this result is. I did the short version so far and one drive had a "read failure" on one of the tests. 
Adding the result up to my original question. Any advice on what this error means about the reliability of this drive ?

Comment: A read failure means you have lost data, and the test stopped at the first
error, so there is still 90% of the surface to check.  See [man
smartctl](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in)
for how to continue the test further with `-t select,...` and the [faq](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/FAQ#ATAdriveisfailingself-testsbutSMARThealthstatusisPASSED.Whatsgoingon) on how to read the attributes table to see if the disk is usable.

Comment: Thank you! @meuh